# regex: Find next or previous letter in the alphabet

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have an Oracle SQl table with 2 colunms, value and positionid, value goes from -10 to 10 and positionid from A01 to K25.

I need to find out which neighboring position have a difference higher or equal to 5. A neighbor position is determined by its positionid according with the alphabet and the number order, something like in the below table:, B02 will have as neighbor positions A01, A02, A03, B01, B03, C01, C02 and C03

```
| A01 | A02 | A03 | A04 |
| B01 | B02 | B03 | B04 |
| C01 | C02 | C03 | C04 |
| D01 | D02 | D03 | D04 |
```

For example:

- Position B02 with value 5 and C03 with value -5 **match** that condition because they are neighbours and the value difference is higher than 5.
- Position B02 with value 5 and C03 with value 4 **doesn`t match** that condition because they are neighbours but the value difference is lower than 5.
- Position A20 with value 5 and E05 with value -5 **doesn't match** the condition because they are not neighbours.

Any suggestion for the SQL query or at least a regex to find those neighbours positions?

| value | positionid |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | A01 |
| -4 | A02 |
| 7 | A03 |
| . | . |
| 4 | C12 |
| 2 | C13 |
| 0 | C14 |

The desired output can be quite simple, just need both positionid and both values.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own versions of regex.)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: What does determine the relationship of two Pos? Why are B02 and C03 neighbours?

Comment: there is still no representative example with desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like the one below. There are comments in the where clause explaining what each portion is doing. The example below is searching the `positionid` **C03** but you can change that value to check a different position.

Also, you can remove the where clause from the `search_pos` common table expression entirely and add the columns to the list of columns being selected and be able to see ALL combinations of positions/values that match the criteria you described.

```sql
WITH
    search_pos
    AS
        (SELECT VALUE, positionid
           FROM positions
          WHERE positionid = 'C03')
SELECT p.VALUE, p.positionid
  FROM positions p, search_pos s
 WHERE --Check to make sure the 1st character (Letter) is the same or a neighboring letter
           SUBSTR (p.positionid, 1, 1) IN
               (SUBSTR (s.positionid, 1, 1),
                CHR (ASCII (SUBSTR (s.positionid, 1, 1)) - 1),
                CHR (ASCII (SUBSTR (s.positionid, 1, 1)) + 1))
       --Check to make sure the 2nd and 3rd characters (numeric) is the same or a neighboring number
       AND TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (p.positionid, 2, 2)) IN
               (TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (s.positionid, 2, 2)),
                TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (s.positionid, 2, 2)) - 1,
                TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (s.positionid, 2, 2)) + 1)
       --Exclude the position currently being searched for
       AND p.positionid <> s.positionid
       --Check that the value has a 5 or greater difference from the value of the position being searched
       AND (p.VALUE >= s.VALUE + 5 OR p.VALUE <= s.VALUE - 5);
```